# Android Google Maps. Calculate the traveled distance onLocationchange and display in textview.?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I am working on a Android Google Map activity Project. I should calculate the traveled distance onLocationchange.
Here i am facing a problem when calculatin the distance. Actual point here is to display the distance traveled in the textview when ever the onlocationchange is triggered.
Here is the code what i have tried.

```
 @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude()*1E6),(int)(location.getLongitude() *1E6));
                path.add(point);
                controller.animateTo(point);
                mapview.invalidate();
                distance();
            }

            public void distance(){
                start = path.get(0);
                stop = path.get(path.size()-1);
                double lat1 = start.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
                double lat2 = stop.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
                double lon1 = start.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
                double lon2 = stop.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
                double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
                double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
                double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
                Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
                double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
                double d = c * 6378.1;
                d =Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("####.###").format(d));
                text.setText(" distance :" + d + "km");
            }
```

And I am passing four locations through DDMS Manual Decimal
Here are those locations.

```
1)lat    -122.084095  This is the start point. and the text view is set to 0kms
                  long     37.422006

                2)lat    -122.085095    The textview distance is set to 0.088kms 
                  long     37.422006  

                3)lat    -122.085095    The textview distance is set to 0.142kms  wroks fine till here
                  long     37.423006    

                4)lat    -122.084095    The text view distance is set to 0.111kms    WTF. now why is that my distance is decreased from 0.142kms to 0.111kms
                  long     37.423006  

                5)4)lat    -122.084095    The text view distance is set to 0.0kms    OMG.. Now the textview shows 0.0kms whats wrong. 
                  long     37.422006
```

Is this the correct way to calculate distance.
What is the mistake  i am doing. I think we should for loop for the array of points. But How?? I dont know...
PLEASE HELP.THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it's saying your distance is 0 when you get back to the original point should set off a lightbulb: What you're actually calculating is the distance from your original point to whatever new point you're emulating, instead of a total distance along the path.

Instead of measuring the distance from point 1 to every other point, you should measure the distance from the last point you were at to the next point and add that to a distance variable you create to hold the total distance.

For example, changing the following should solve your problem:

```
start = path.get(path.size()-2);
//Be sure to check that there's at least 2 points in your array with an if statement!!
```

Then later:

```
totalDistance += d;
textView.setText("Text" + totalDistance);
```

where totalDistance is some double you define earlier.

Comment: Sure, I edited my post. If you insist on storing your points in the path list, this is how I would do it. Make sure path.size() > 1 before you assign start, otherwise you'll get a NullPointerException. And totalDistance is some variable you define in your class outside of onLocationChanged.